# Performance issue due to CSS positioning

Tags: html, css, performance

Will it make any performance degradation if I use lot absolute and fixed positioning in my HTML app?

Any HTML experts?

Comment: do you have experience in building HTML enterprise apps? Usually we don't allow screen to have scroll bars.In this case, while page re-sizes i call onresize and give width and height based on current dimensions. i set width and height in this way for many elements. still now there is no performance issue. Is this right way?

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer, no.

More complex answer, no, at least not measurably slower. The page will still be rendering the same amount of objects whether it decides where to place them or you explicity tell it where to place them.

Comment: do you have experience in building HTML enterprise apps? Usually we don't allow screen to have scroll bars.In this case, while page re-sizes i call onresize and give width and height based on current dimensions. i set width and height in this way for many elements. still now there is no performance issue. Is this right way?

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't! :) Setting position variables will not affect performance as it not not loading anything externally, just telling where the object must be placed. In some cases, it is a necessity to be used.

Answer (score 0):

No it wont. Just keep DOM as simple as possible without making it too deep. And use CSS selectors with maximum level of 3 qualifiers. The lesser the better.